# No known class method for selector 'setDisableCards:' in payumoney iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, payumoney

I am facing the following issues while using payumoney in my iOS project.

[image]

No known class method for selector 'setDisableCards:'.
No known class method for selector 'setDisableNetbanking:'.
No known class method for selector 'setDisableWallet:'.

```
[PlugNPlay setDisableCards:NO];    
[PlugNPlay setDisableNetbanking:NO];    
[PlugNPlay setDisableWallet:YES];
```

Comment: hello, I guess from your question that those methods should rely on an instance, rather than on a class. One should always read errors.

Comment: @art-divin nope, those errors are not saying that those are instance methods, but that there are **no class methods** with those names. And in fact, as per jtouzy's answer, they were completely removed from the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue on GitHub](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-IOS-SDK/issues/35) indicates that those functions has been removed from SDK.

And yes, they were removed from exposed header :

https://github.com/payu-intrepos/PayUMoney-IOS-SDK/blob/master/PlugNPlay/PlugNPlay.framework/Headers/PlugNPlay.h